# Why are some websites' HTML and JavaScript so unreadable?

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to figure out what was going on in Facebook's login page and viewed the source in my browser. Some of the code is so unreadable it almost looks like somebody was just typing randomly:

```
<script>
function envFlush(a){
    function b(c){for(var d in a)c[d]=a[d];}
    if(window.requireLazy){window.requireLazy(['Env'],b);}
    else{window.Env=window.Env||{};b(window.Env);}
}
envFlush({
    "ajaxpipe_token":"AXjTsqcPXwT0nKMR",
    "lhsh":"8AQEln95N",
    "khsh":"0`sj`e`rm`s-0fdu^gshdoer-0gc^eurf-3gc^eurf;
    1;
    enbtldou;
    fduDmdldourCxO`ld-2YLMIuuqSdptdru;qsnunuxqd;
    rdoe-0unjdojnx-0unjdojnx0-0gdubi^rdbsduOdv-0`sj`e`r-0q`xm`r-0StoRbs`qhof"
});
</script>
```

Why is the HTML and JavaScript of most major websites so horrible and hard to read?

Answer (score 5):

Most of the JavaScript code you will find online, especially on big websites like Facebook, is minified, compressed and sometimes even obfuscated.

**Minification** of JavaScript is mostly done because of performance reasons. All unnecessary whitespace (+ line breaks) and unnecessary elements like comments will be deleted to make the code as lightweight as possible. This results in faster loading times, reduces the server load and improves so the user experience.

**Obfuscation** is a way to render code unreadable, without destroying it's functionality. It is mostly done to protect the code and to make stealing it more difficult.

There are tools online (most of them called "beautifier" or "prettifier"), that can revert said minimization.

Answer (score 0):

why not?

Web sites are not designed for human reading.  They are designed often for performance (minimum number of characters make less to transmit - including stripping all white-space) and often they are DELIBERATELY trying to make it hard to read, as a way of protecting their intellectual property.  There are actually tools out there designed to take "beautiful" code and deliberately make it ugly - for exactly this reason!